# How to see the python script used for an addon in a .blend file

Tags: python

Some time ago, I wrote some scripts to rotate vectors in blender. I am not a blender expert. I have the files. I want to see the python script that I wrote.

The files work fine but although I can see the console and blender runs the code, I can't find out how to see the code.

For completeness I wrote the script inside the python editor built into blender. When I open the .blend file, the script runs automatically and generates the 3D image.

Can I do this?

Comment: You wrote some script in where? Text editor or an external file? How did the code been run? Is it automatically been run? You have what files?

Comment: I wrote the script inside the python editor built into blender. When I open then .blend file, the script runs automatically and generates the 3D image. I am happy to upload the file if I have somewhere I can do that.

Comment: When you create a text-editor region, and click the selector dropdown to the left of  'New' at the bottom of it, does your script  appear as a text data-block in the ,blend file?

Answer (score -1):

split the screen and change the 3d viewport to text editor , click on the **Open** and select your python file , and you should get it , and i think you can also open them in notepad(not sure , try that for future)

Comment: The python script was written in the blender text editor.

Comment: I have improved the wording of my question

Comment: try opening it in notepad++